# Trying to show uploaded image in my "Edit form"

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, upload

I have this code code below to upload image in a foder uploads/year/month, if this directory does not exist it will create if exists I only do the upload.

After this code, Im doing a insert into my "news" table with this thumb info and the other *table news* fields.

And it is working fine, Im inserting without any error, its inserting in my database, and the image file is uploading with sucess in my uploads/year/month folder.

But now in my other file "news-edit.php", to edit my news, and I want to show the thumb file in my label.

Im trying to do this for hours and its not working, somebody there can give me a help understanding what is happening?

**My php code to upload image**

```
if(!empty($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'])){

    $folder  = '../uploads/';
    $year    = date('Y');
    $month    = date('m');
if(file_exists($folder.$resultReadEdit['thumb']) && !is_dir($folder.$resultReadEdit['thumb']))
{
unlink($folder.$resultReadEdit['thumb']);
}

if(!file_exists($folder.$year)){

mkdir($folder.$year,0755);


}

if(!file_exists($folder.$year.'/'.$month)){
    mkdir($folder.$year.'/'.$month,0755);
}

    $img = $_FILES['thumb'];
    $ext = substr($img['name'],-3);
    $f['thumb'] = $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$f['url'].'.'.$ext;
    uploadImage($img['tmp_name'], $f['url'].'.'.$ext, '300', $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/');

}
```

My php to show the image file:

```
<label class="line">
<?php
    $folder  = '../uploads/';
    $year    = date('Y');
    $month   = date('m');
    echo '<a href="'.$folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$resultReadEdit['thumb'].'"  rel="Shadowbox">';
    echo '<img src="'.$folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$resultReadEdit['thumb'].'"  width="50" />';
    echo '</a>';
    print_r($resultReadEdit['thumb']);
?>   
<input type="file" class="fileinput" name="thumb" size="60" />
</label>
```

**What Im getting:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your generated html source code. Since your `print_r($resultReadEdit['thumb'])` is returning

```
2014/04/title-of-my-news.png
```

you are saving `$resultReadEdit['thumb']` as `year/month/thumb` so your html source code probably is looking like

```
src="uploads/2014/04/2014/04/title-of-my-news.png"
```

So try changing

```
echo '<img src="'.$folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$resultReadEdit['thumb'].'"  width="50" />';
```

to

```
echo '<img src="'.$folder.$resultReadEdit['thumb'].'"  width="50" />';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Of course that was the problem, many hours in front of computer its not good to the brain loll... Thanks!